# Separate column data based on comma characters using pandas regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': ['V583 ,ATTENTION, PRIMARY','Y9207,INDOOR LIVING, sEcondary',' z526, liver,primary ','12345678, test, secondary',',project,']})
```

I would like to split/segregate column `val` data based on `comma` character.

For instance, All characters `before 1st comma` should go to `first` column
Similarly, All characters `after 1st comma` and `before 2nd comma` should go to `second` column
likewise, All characters `after 2nd comma` and `before 3rd comma` should go to `third` column

I tried the below

```
df['val'].astype(str).str.extract(r'\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)',expand=True)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Series.str.extractall`

We can `extract` all the occurrences of capturing group specified as regex pattern then `unstack` to reshape.

```
df['val'].str.extractall(r'([^,]+)(?:\s*,\s*|$)')[0].unstack()
```

---

```
match         0              1          2
0         V583       ATTENTION    PRIMARY
1         Y9207  INDOOR LIVING  sEcondary
2          z526          liver   primary 
3      12345678           test  secondary
4       project            NaN        NaN
```

**Regex details:**

- `([^,]+)` : First capturing group

  - `[^,]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[,]` one or more times.
- `(?:\s*,\s*|$)` : Non capturing group

  - `\s*,\s*` : First alternative

    - `\s*` : Matches any white space character zero or more times
    - `,` : Matches the character comma literally
    - `\s*` : Matches any white space character zero or more times
  - `$` : Second alternative asserts position at the end of line

PS: This method can also work if you have **any number of comma delimited strings.**

Comment: THANKS, upvoted.. marking this as a solution for its generalizability and detailed explanation

Comment: @TheGreat Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. Using [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function of Pandas here. Simple explanation would be: mentioning regex in extract to create 3 new columns in DataFrame. Its basically creating 3 capturing groups for each new fields as per shown samples.

```
df[["first", "second", "third"]] =  df['val'].str.extract(r'^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)$',expand=True)
```

[Here is online demo of above regex](https://regex101.com/r/fHNYGc/3)

df's output will be as follows:

```
                              val     first         second       third
0        V583 ,ATTENTION, PRIMARY     V583       ATTENTION     PRIMARY
1  Y9207,INDOOR LIVING, sEcondary     Y9207  INDOOR LIVING   sEcondary
2            z526, liver,primary       z526          liver    primary 
3       12345678, test, secondary  12345678           test   secondary
4                       ,project,                  project
```

Comment: but I get additional columns with headers `4`,`5` and `6` with values `None`

Comment: @TheGreat, ohh, with your shown samples, it worked fine for me. Could you please do let me know if your actual df is same as shown df?

Comment: yes, its same as sample df...not sure why I get additional column in original data.. But yes, it works fine in sample data

Comment: @TheGreat, may be you have more commas in your actual data? If yes then try changing my solution to `df[["first", "second", "third"]] =  df['val'].str.extract(r'^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)',expand=True)` once, this will only catch values till 3rd comma. Let me know how it goes, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.extract` here as follows:

```py
df["first"] = df["val"].str.extract(r'^\s*(.*?)\s*,')
df["second"] = df["val"].str.extract(r',\s*(.*?)\s*,')
df["third"] = df["val"].str.extract(r',\s*([^,]*)$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split(expand=True)`

```
  df.join(df['val'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'first',1:'second',2:'third'}))

                              val     first         second       third
0        V583 ,ATTENTION, PRIMARY     V583       ATTENTION     PRIMARY
1  Y9207,INDOOR LIVING, sEcondary     Y9207  INDOOR LIVING   sEcondary
2            z526, liver,primary       z526          liver    primary 
3       12345678, test, secondary  12345678           test   secondary
4                       ,project,                  project
```

Comment: but I get additional columns with headers `4`,`5` and `6` with values `None`

Comment: You have additional comas. You could slice the extra columns out `df1.iloc[:,:4]`